# Excel IF statement formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help with creating a formula that will output only information within certain boundaries.

The phrase `%ese_waɾm@ikuna_dahun_ɾegalota%` is in column `L1` and I want to print out the word that starts with the letter "i".
The boundaries of the word are "@" and "_".

So far I have

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@i",L134)),"i","")
```

But this formula only prints out the letter "i" and I want to formula to be able to print out the word in every instance so that the word column will be "inkuna".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This will return whatever is between `@` and the first `_` that follows it, as long as the character that follows the `@` is an `i`:

```
=IF(SEARCH("@",L4)+1 = SEARCH("i",L4),MID(L4,SEARCH("@",L4)+1,SEARCH("_",L4,SEARCH("i",L4))-SEARCH("i",L4)),"")
```

Comment: I don't think the `i` is fixed. I think OP just wants everything between `@` and the first subsequent `_`

Comment: I based my answer on the fact that OP's formula included `SEARCH("@i"` but you may be right. @Meghan -- if you could clarify? Perhaps explain what your ultimate goal is?

Comment: true, "The boundaries of the word are "@" and "_"" conflicts with the `SEARCH("@i"`